# Function id="no-link" is not working properly

Tags: javascript

I use id = "no-link" without problem with an image. But with a text and an anchor the result is not good. Clicking on the link has no effect.

Thank you for your help.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
          setTimeout(function () {
               
                $('a[href]#no-link').each(function () {
                    var href = this.href;
    
                    $(this).removeAttr('href').css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function () {
                        if (href.toLowerCase().indexOf("#") >= 0) {
    
                        } else {
                            window.open(href, '_blank');
                        }
                    });
                });
    
          }, 500);
    });
```

```html
   <a href="/indexGB.html"id="no-link"><img src="images/GB flag.jpg" width="29" height="29" alt="photo"class="myphoto2"></a>    
  <p><a href="/indexGB.html#def"id="no-link"> 정의 </a></p
```

Comment: you cant have more than one of the same ID. Use class instead

Comment: id must be unique and when you select element by id then return an element and you can't use each

Comment: I found a solution in stackoverflow.com/
<p><a onclick = "location.href='#def'"id="no-link"> test </a></p>
this allows to use id="no-link on several place on a same page.